# SQL: Query for getting date wise increment

Tags: sql, analytics, vertica

Need to count the number of user being added every day, given a date range from date and to date, an e.g is shown below:

```
select 
  '2017-06-01' as myDate
, count(distinct user_id) 
from tbl_stats 
where date(dateTime)<='2017-06-01' 
union all 
select
  '2017-06-02' as myDate
, count(distinct user_id) 
from tbl_stats 
where date(dateTime)<='2017-06-02'
```

The output would be like:

```
 reportDate | count 
------------+-------
 2017-06-01 |  2467
 2017-06-02 |  2470
```

So, I will just have fromDate and toDate and i would need date wise distinct user count in the table. I will not be using any procedures or loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(ts.dateTime) AS reportDate
    , COUNT(distinct ts.user_id) AS userCount
FROM tbl_stats AS ts
WHERE ts.dateTime >= @lowerBoundDate 
    AND ts.dateTime < TIMESTAMPADD('DAY', 1, @upperBoundDate)
GROUP BY DATE(ts.dateTime)
```

Comment: This will give count of distinct user for each day, required is no of total distinct user before the @lowerBoundDate , and then each day the user count gets added up to the next date.

Answer (score 0):

To get cumulative (distinct) users count per day, use following, replace custom dates given in following example with your start and end dates.

```
WITH test_data AS (
        SELECT '2017-01-01'::date as event_date, 1::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-01'::date as event_date, 2::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-02'::date as event_date, 1::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-02'::date as event_date, 2::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-02'::date as event_date, 3::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-03'::date as event_date, 4::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-03'::date as event_date, 5::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-04'::date as event_date, 1::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-04'::date as event_date, 2::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-04'::date as event_date, 3::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-04'::date as event_date, 4::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-04'::date as event_date, 5::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-04'::date as event_date, 6::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-05'::date as event_date, 3::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-05'::date as event_date, 4::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-05'::date as event_date, 5::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-05'::date as event_date, 6::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-05'::date as event_date, 7::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-05'::date as event_date, 8::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-06'::date as event_date, 7::int as user_id
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-01-06'::date as event_date, 9::int as user_id
)
SELECT event_date,
       COUNT(distinct user_id) AS distinct_user_per_day,
       SUM(COUNT(distinct user_id)) OVER (ORDER BY event_date) AS cumulative_user_count
FROM test_data
WHERE event_date >= '2017-01-01' 
      AND 
      event_date <= '2017-01-06'
GROUP BY 
      event_date
```

Comment: This will give cumulative_user_count with respect to the previous day count like :
    date    | distinct_user_per_day | cumulative_user_count 
    ------------+-----------------------+-----------------------
    2017-06-01 |                   385 |                   385
    2017-06-02 |                   372 |                   757
 
So we are getting previous day user count added up to current day user count , actually most user are common in both days and required is total unique users including both all previous days.